# Android ListView element invalidate() does not redraw

Tags: android, listview, invalidation, redraw

In my Android App, I have a ListView which contains several elements. For certain user inputs (touch events), it happens that one element in the ListView calls invalidate() on itself. The problem is that sometimes, the element then redraws itself and sometimes not. When it does not redraw itself after invalidate() has been called, I need to scroll the ListView in order to get the desired redraw. Of course, I don't want that.
It is to mention that I never call listview.invalidate() but only element.invalidate(). Has anyone an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to call notifyDataSetChanged() once element finish drawing.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we all get older, we get wiser. My problem was that I did not use `convertView` in the Adapter's `getView` method but kept all the views in an ArrayList. Bad practice, ladies and gents. Use `convertView` and everything will work buttery smooth.